# How to loop addEventListener to apply style property in Javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, addeventlistener

I am working on a `TODO` list. Upon receiving user input, I would also like to give users the option of clicking on completed tasks and having Javascript apply `line-through` style.

Here is my code:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(){
        var finish = document.getElementById('div'); 
        finish.style.setProperty("text-decoration", "line-through");
    });
```

At this point, the click event works but the `line-through` style is only applied to the top most task only.

What is the best way to loop through the task list so that style can be applied to all. Here is an image to illustrate.

[image]

I am a new to Javascript.

Thanks

Comment: `style.textDecoration='line-through'`

Comment: Give a common class name to all elements on which you want to apply style `text-decoration: line-through`...

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question or the task I am trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Aaai aai aai some mistakes there :)

```
 var finish = document.getElementById('div');
```

I suspect you have reused the id 'div' on every line?
An id is unique ! So it will only apply on one thing. 
Also its pretty messy to use the id 'div' :) Since div is a tagname

I also think your intention is to click on the line and do a `line-through` ?

The listener you have added 'fires' when you click on the entire webpage and not only the line?

You should do something like

```
var firstline = document.getElementById('firstline');
firstline.onclick = function()
{
    this.style.setProperty("text-decoration", "line-through");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/L1awL7rw/1/

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function(){
if(event.target.tagName=='LABEL'){
    event.target.setAttribute('class','strike');
}
});
```

I have taken few `label` elements, on click over them, adding a class `strike`, which applies CSS rule `text-decoration:line-through`. Answer would have been more specific as per your requirement if you had shared some HTML code..

Also, as you have asked to loop through each element and attach listener using `addEventListener`, I find this approach not as awesome as in comparison with `Event Delegation`.

Comment: @hanshenrik  Whenever an event occurs, an `event` object is created and passed sequentially to the event listeners...Read more about it here..https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event

Comment: then why is the event also passed as first parameter to the listener function? :o

Comment: Both way it is possible..either through `function(e){//where 'e' is event object passed }` or `function(){// directly accessing 'event' object}`...